# Bug with RAM, only half of ram slots are used

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

I have a problem with my RAM.

Main OS: WIN 10 PRO 64bit

Motherboard:

ASUS M5A97 R2.0

Ram(4slots): 2x4GB + 2x8GB

RAM model:

HyperX 8GB KIT DDR3 1600MHz

HyperX 16GB KIT DDR3 1600MHz

So motherboard have 4 ram slots, while only 2 work as usage, other 2 is only installed.

In bios north bridge i have dim0-dim3, where only dim02 and dim03 work as usage...dim0 and dim1 dava just installed...

I try combine them as 4+8 4+8 for dualchanel etc...but nothing work... If i remove ram from 2slots that are usage and only place ram in slots that are installed - PC not start...

Only that same 2slots work... Ram works as 4+8 => 12GB usage...its not problem with compatibility of ram

But why all 4slots are installed, bios know about 4slots, but use only 2?

I try in win reset max memory limit, enable whole maping in bios etc...nothing...

CPU-Z report:

https://valid.x86.fr/xe13rv

Screenshots from bios and windows:

[windows info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NevJ2.jpg)
[bios ram usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgF1D.jpg)
[bios 4slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTyyh.jpg)

Comment: According to the manual with two modules you should use slots A2/B2 for compatibility. I would suggest to try a 8+8 set-up and use it if it works stable.

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. Actually i have 2x4GB in left slots and 2x8GB in right slots...right slots working everytime as usade...left slots only installed...

Comment: Here is IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Mic.jpg
Only in B mobules RAM is working for use...A module only installed... Or what you mean?

Comment: I try that combo A2+B2 as 8GB ram and A1+B1 as 4GB, but system work only as 12GB ram...from module B...

Comment: That is the wrong order. Memory slots for dual channel are always interleaved, hence you have to use A1/B1=4GB A2/B2=8GB. If that does not work there is an incompatibility and I would recommend to just use 16GB.

Comment: Yes, I try that combo A2+B2 for 8GB ram and A1+B1 for 4GB, but system work only as 12GB ram. That was working only slot B1+B2 = 4GB+8GB = 12GB as use ram...Compatibility with 4gb and 8gb ram working well

Comment: New report...https://valid.x86.fr/30hd6h
A1+B1 4gb and A2+B2 8gb..not working

Answer (score 0):

Your RAM is properly working. Your first screenshot (windows info) proves that Windows is able to see all 24 gigabyte which proves it is really there.

However Windows will only use 16 GB (15.9 available as it says in the screenshot).
This is in most cases caused by a maximum memory limit set to 16 GB in the Windows advanced setings. (And it is possible this is set without you doing it yourself. There have been a couple of games in the past that had a problem with more than 16 GB of RAM and very "helpfully" took it upon themselves to limit the RAM.)

To check this:
Run the msconfig program.
Go to the "Boot" tab.
Click on the "Advanced Options" button.
A new window will up where you can set the maximum RAM Windows will use.
Remove the check mark to de-activate and reboot to apply the new setting.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i try it but nothing... I have disabled that checkbox for max memory limit, in windows settings...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem (RAM detected, but not usable) before with an AM3 platform system, in my case it was caused by a bent CPU pin, which I was (luckily) able to straighten out and fix. Check your CPU pins are all straight and that there isn't any debris in the CPU socket. Check the RAM slots themselves as well, there could be debris in there.

If you believe it's an OS issue try booting a live Linux environment [(Ubuntu, for example)](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) and see if all the memory shows up and is usable there. If it is, you know it's a configuration problem in Windows rather than a hardware or BIOS settings issue.

Comment: `$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep -iE 'total|free|avail'`

Comment: What about that linux command?

Comment: I tried that but pins on CPU are ok... ram slots too...not working :(